# MAXREPEAT issue when running Python 2.7 from MacPorts

Tags: python, macos, macports

I'm running into some issues with running python2.7 from MacPorts.

Here's a list of the available Python versions:

```
$ sudo port select python
Available versions for python:
    none
    python25-apple
    python26-apple
    python27 (active)
    python27-apple
```

When I set `python27` to be active (as above), I get the following error when running `python`:

```
$ sudo port select --set python python27
Selecting 'python27' for 'python' succeeded. 'python27' is now active.
$ python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 548, in <module>
    main()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 530, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 266, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 241, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 231, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 516, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 449, in get_config_vars
    import re
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 105, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py", line 14, in <module>
    import sre_parse
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py", line 17, in <module>
    from sre_constants import *
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.py", line 18, in <module>
    from _sre import MAXREPEAT
ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT
```

The version of the port I have installed is (according to `sudo port installed`):

```
python27 @2.7.5_1
python27 @2.7.5_1+universal (active)
```

I do not get the above error when running `python2.7`, only when I run `python` in the shell.

```
$ which python2.7
/opt/local/bin/python2.7

$ which python
/opt/local/bin/python
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced the same issue. A quick and easy workaround is to add an alias in ~/.profile:

```
alias python='python2.7'
```

If you don't have a .profile file already, just create one. Open a new instance of terminal and python should work fine with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Appears to be a problem with links to executables, particularly vim/MacVim.  I resolved the issue for myself by following the discussion [here](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/241).

There is also more material [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue18050).

Hope this helps.

Max